# Passing variable to html href

Tags: javascript, html, sendgrid

I'm having issues passing an env variable to an html href value.

I'm using a working example I have that is a message that comes in via email. It's essentially what I'm going for, but I'm trying to insert an enviroment variable where the `http://localhost:4200/wins` is

```
const msg = {
  to: notificationResults[0].email,
  from: 'myapp@DONOTREPLY.com',
  subject: 'You\'ve won! Woohoo!',
  html: '<a href="http://localhost:4200/wins' +
    payload.id +
    "/" +
    token +
    '">Please visit your My Wins page to complete payment.</a>'
};
```

My attempt to add the env variable

```
const msg = {
    to: notificationResults[0].email,
    from: 'myapp@DONOTREPLY.com',
    subject: 'You\'ve won! Woohoo!',
    html: '<a href="'process.env.WEBSITE_URL + "/wins" +
    '">Please visit your My Wins page to complete payment.</a>'
    };
```

but on `process.` there's the error

```
',' expected.ts(1005)
```

What am I doing wrong? I appreciate the help!

Comment: Sure, look at your code again, closely: what's wrong with `'<a href="'process.env.WEBSITE_URL` ?. Now, you could just add the missing symbol, but you shouldn't: the problem of concatenation screwups was solved in modern JS using modern string syntax. Don't use `+` for concatenating strings. Use template strings, e.g. ```html: `<a href="${linkURL}">${linkLabel}</a>`,...``` with ```linkURL = `${process.env.WEBSITE_URL}/wins/`;``` and ```linkLabel = `Please visit your My Wins page to complete payment.`;```. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Missing + before process.env.WEB...

Comment: The ```+``` was the problem. I've also added some `` so I can add the variables into string too. Thanks for the help!